# Simple increment counter doesn't work in android app

Tags: android

sounds stupid but a simple increment counter doesn't work in my android app.

I have two activities in the app and one counter in each, which is incremented each time when onCreate method is called. When I'm switching between the activities the first one works well, but the other one just doesn't count.

I'm using the same line to create the variable like this:

```
private int mCreate;
```

Then I'm just incrementing it in the same way in each class in the onCreate method:

```
mCreate++;
```

This variable is used in two different classes, so it shouldn't be a problem. This is my first android app, so I need some help.

The whole code of the second activity. I'm not showing the first one because the only difference is in the setOnClickListener method.

```
public class ActivityTwo extends Activity {

private final static String TAG = "Lab-ActivityTwo";

private int mCreate;

private TextView mTvCreate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);
    mTvCreate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.create);

    Button closeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bClose); 
    closeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();

        }
    });

}

    Log.i(TAG, "Entered the onCreate() method"); // to check if the inCreate method was called

    mCreate++;
    mTvCreate.setText("onCreate() calls: " + mCreate);
    Log.i(TAG, "mCreate = " + mCreate); // just to check if I implemented the TextView worng
    displayCounts();

}
```

Comment: Can you explain a little better and maybe show more of your code? Should they be two different counters or one holding a single value?

Comment: Local variables in an activity are recreated everytime oncreate is called. If you need to maintain the variable, you should put it somewhere else, for example in a static variable in your Application class.

Comment: @codeMagic I've added come more code. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Opoo the variables are declared as private inside the classes but outside the onCreate method, so it should work properly. The question is that this code works for the first activity and doesn't for the second one.

Comment: @Oleg you're always getting a value of 1 right? I'm not sure what your goal is with the counter

Answer (score 1):

The reason your second counter doesn't work because after finishing an activity all the variables and objects are destroyed and make free by GC. The next time you call for that activity it is created from scratch and your count remain same everytime.

Like @Opoo said if you want to get count you should define static variable in Application class.

Comment: Yes, I've just reached the same answer. Thanks! I didn't got right the activity lifecycle statements. The first activity was switching between onRestart and onStop methods, thats why all the variables were alive and the counter worked properly. The second activity destroyed with all variables each time as the button was pressed with finish() method on it.